# Update Riak json data via ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, riak

For example I have JSON object:

```
    {
    "title":"Computer science"
    "comments":["Good article","Need updates"]
    }
```

and I have one new comment that I want to add into that object stored on Riak.
Path to this object on Riak is `192.168.56.12:10018/riak/articles/article1`.

How can I update this object directly from code if I use ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (found here: [Introducing Riak, Part 1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-riak1/), search for "updating an object"), you do a HTTP PUT to that same Url, with the data that should be put in riak.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using one of the client libraries out there with .Net support if you can:

http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/libraries/

There are three libraries currently listed under C#/.Net. The CorrugatedIron client (http://corrugatediron.org/) is in the early stages of moving towards official support (https://github.com/basho-labs/CorrugatedIron).

Answer (score -1):

Pass this JSON object to code behind and modify it according to your need and return back the JSON object